# 1 Char привести к byte[]

Tags: java

Как перевести `1 char` к `byte[]`? Не предлагать переводы к `String`

Comment: char c = 1; byte[] b = {(byte)c};

Comment: А я думаю так:
char c = 'c';
            byte[] b = new byte[2];
            b[0] = (byte)c;
            b[1] = (byte)(c << 4);

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov зачем вы на 4 бита влево сдвигаете? если он хочет из char 2 байта получить, то надо char cc = 257; byte[] b = {(byte) (cc >> 8), (byte) cc};

Comment: @Russtam Ага, неправильно сдвинул. Но суть понятна: char 2 байта, т.е. когда приводим к byte домножаем на маску 0x00FF. Поторопился я..

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = 1;
byte b = (byte) c;
```

типо так?
это вроде называется явное преобразование типов...

Comment: Автор имел ввиду массив `byte[]`